# How to check if a checkbox is checked in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple checkboxes and I would like to know if one of them is checked. My code does not give me any error, but I don't get the results I am expecting. When I run the code always get the first alert which is inside the for loop. The following is my code:

```
function validate(){


    if(document.getElementById('postTW').checked || document.getElementById('postFB') ){

        var checker = document.getElementsByName('twitter[]');
        for (var i = 0; i < checker.length; i++) {
            if(checker[i].checked){
                return true;
            }

            else{

                alert("Not enough arguments ");

                return false;
            }
        };

    }


    else{
        alert("Not enough arguments to submit the form");

        return false;
    }

}
```

My form is method = post and looks like the following

```
<input class="twGroup" type="checkbox" name="twitter[]" value="x"/> 
<input class="twGroup" type="checkbox" name="twitter[]" value="y"/>
<input class="twGroup" type="checkbox" name="twitter[]" value="z"/>
```

Comment: can you also post your markup/fiddle?

Comment: Can you show some html of your page ?

Comment: This will only test the first checker.

Comment: @Arjuna I just edited my question, you can see part of the form now

Comment: @Bart How can I iterate through all the checkboxs, thanx in advanced

Comment: don't use return in the loop.

Comment: Is this correct `document.getElementById('postFB') ){`  ?

and should be
`document.getElementById('postFB').checked){`

Comment: you have written `document.getElementById('postTW').checked` but I don't see the ID's anywhere. please post some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a logical error in your code. As written, if the first checkbox is **not** checked, then you will fall through to the *else* statement and display the alert. You should simply get rid of the first *else* statement and move the first alert outside of the for-loop:

```
function validate() {
    if(document.getElementById('postTW').checked || document.getElementById('postFB') ) {
        var checker = document.getElementsByName('twitter[]');
        for (var i = 0; i < checker.length; i++) {
            if(checker[i].checked){
                return true;
            }
        };

        // else fall through
        alert("Not enough arguments ");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("Not enough arguments to submit the form");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it works, I forgot to get rid of the else part. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This code checks only 1st checkbox because of return:

```
for (var i = 0; i < checker.length; i++) {
    if(checker[i].checked) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        alert("Not enough arguments ");
        return false;
    }
};
```

Try this:

```
var checked_flag = false;
for (var i = 0; i < checker.length; i++) {
    if(checker[i].checked) {
        checked_flag = true;
    }         
};
return checked_flag;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are there logic errors in the following code?

```
for (var i = 0; i < checker.length; i++) {
        if(checker[i].checked){
            return true;
        }

        else{

            alert("Not enough arguments ");

            return false;
        }
    };
```

I assume you want something like this:

```
var flag=false;
for (var i = 0; i < checker.length; i++) {
            if(checker[i].checked){
                flag=true;
            }
        };
if (!flag){
        alert("Not enough arguments ");
}
```

Comment: yeah, I followed a different approach but I am sure this woks as well. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use a flag that will return `false` if any checkbox of name `twitter[]` is not checked

```
function validate(){
 if(document.getElementById('postTW').checked || document.getElementById('postFB').checked ){
   var result = true;
    var checker = document.getElementsByName('twitter[]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checker.length; i++) {
        if(!checker[i].checked){
            alert("Not enough arguments ");
            result = false;
            return;
        }
    };
}
else{
    alert("Not enough arguments to submit the form");
    result = false;
}
return result
```

}

Comment: I think your approach is right, but i solve my problem already. Thank you very much though

Answer (score 1):

wrap your checkboxes around `<form>` element.
Example shown:

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="twitter[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="twitter[]" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="twitter[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="twitter[]" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="twitter[]" />
</form>
```

Apply Javascript as shown.

```
    if (document.getElementById('postTW').checked || document.getElementById('postFB')) {
        var myform = document.forms.myform;
        var elems = myform.elements['twitter[]'];
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            if (elems[i].checked) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        alert("Not enough arguments to submit the form");
        return false;

    } else {
        alert("Not enough arguments to submit the form");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, somebody else suggested your solution and it works perfectly

Comment: you are fine, at least you knew the answer which is always good

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think you should write:

```
if(document.getElementById('postTW').checked || document.getElementById('postFB').checked ){
```

instead of:

```
if(document.getElementById('postTW').checked || document.getElementById('postFB') ){
```